# How can I make a valid concatenated full file path?

Tags: bash, shell, concatenation, filenames, filepath

How can I make a valid constructed full file path for copy command?
I want to construct a valid file path that Will be read it by cp command as a path, where my lost file is located at, and Will be copied to another directory. The problem is that cp command doesnt recognize it as a path. I hope and appreciate, you can help me solving this problem.

*The file and directory exists.

*The full file path were constructed by concatenating `$fname` and `$path`.

*My lost file is named `12345678.xml`

**script**

```
 17   for((i=0;i<${#array[@]}-1;i+=2));do
 18     path=$(find "/path/sourcefolder" -name "*zipfolder*" -exec grep -l "Mylostfile" {} + )
 19     fname=$(find "/path/sourcefolder" -name "*zipfolder*" -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep "12345678.xml" | awk ' { printf $4 }')
 20     fullpath="$path/$fname"
 21     cp -t "/path/Desktop" "$fullpath"
 22    done
```

**Actual output**

`Test_v2.sh: line 20: /path/zipfolder/12345678.xml: No such file or directory 
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory`

**Desired output**

Copy the file in another directory

**Additional comments #1:**
I added set -xv an this is the result.

```
++ find /path/sourcefolder -name '*zipfolder*' -exec grep -l 12345678 '{}' +
+ path=/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip
++ find /path/sourcefolder -name '*zipfolder*' -exec unzip -l '{}' ';'
++ grep 12345678
++ awk ' { printf $4 }'
+ fname=12345678.xml
+ set -xv
+ fullpath=
+ /path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml
Test_v2.sh: line 21: /path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml: No such file or directory
+ cp -t /path/Desktop ''
+ cp: cannot stat '': Not a directory
```

**Additional comments #2:**
The space between `fullpath=` and `"$path/$fname"` is eliminated as suggested and this is the following result.

```
++ find /path/sourcefolder -name '*zipfolder*' -exec grep -l 12345678 '{}' +
+ path=/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip
++ find /path/sourcefolder -name '*zipfolder*' -exec unzip -l '{}' ';'
++ grep 12345678
++ awk ' { printf $4 }'
+ fname=12345678.xml
+ set -xv
+ fullpath=/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml
+ cp -t /path/Desktop ''
+ cp: cannot stat '/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml': Not a directory
```

Comment: I don't think the error message comes from the *cp* line which you showed, because the message complains about an empty argument, but *fullpath* must, by construction, contain at least one slash. Also, you forgot to tell us which line is line 20. I suggest to run the script with `-x`. BTW, according to the man-page of *cp*, the correct syntax would be `cp -t /path/Desktop "$fullpath"`. However, I don't think that this is the reason for the error. At least my *cp* is also happy with getting -t at the end.

Comment: Try putting set -xv prior to the lines mentioned and see exactly what is being set and returned.

Comment: @user1924428 Updated! I added set -xv as grail suggested and its result and changed the cp syntax as user1924428 also suggested.

Comment: in `fullpath= "$path/$fname"`, the extra space after the `=` mess things up, as it is understood as "execute the `"$path/$fname"` command with the `fullpath` environment variable set to the empty string". I'm not sure this is the only problem (in particular I doubt that `/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml` is a valid path), but it's a first step

Comment: @Aaron I updated the questions with your suggestions

Comment: I saw but I have no idea what's wrong now. I don't see why `cp` would expect your `$fullpath` to be a directory since it seems like `-t` is correctly followed by a correct directory. Have you checked my answer otherwise? I feel like it makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: Oh wait, remember how I said `/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml` wasn't a correct path? If `/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip` is a zip **file** as the success of `unzip -l` seems to point out, `/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/12345678.xml` isn't a valid path, because `/path/sourcefolder/zipfolder.zip/` isn't a directory, which is what `cp` is probably complaining about.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Aaron got another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do could be simply implemented as follows :

```
find "/path/sourcefolder" -name "*zipfolder*" -exec unzip -p {} '*12345678.xml' > "/path/Desktop/12345678.xml" \;
```

It extracts a file `12345678.xml` from anywhere in the found zip to `/path/Desktop/12345678.xml` by using `unzip`'s `-p` flag to print the content of the file to stdout and redirecting stdout to the target file.

Comment: Alright, wow. You nailed it! It does the copy of the content to the xml to where I want to. thumbs up. thank you so much Aaron!

Comment: @JafetSoto You're welcome ! I didn't know `unzip` accepted wildcards as file selectors until I tried to answer your question, and it was a nice discovery :)

Comment: Really interesting discovery though, this helped me a lot since I was almost giving up finding a solution but you and the other guys that also helped me, make this world a better place.